# WCF wsdualhttpbinding client without elevation

Tags: c#, wcf, callback, wsdualhttpbinding

I've created a Windows Service (server) and a WPF (client) that uses WCFs wsdualhttpbinding callback functionality. Everything between the two pieces of software works correctly but the problem I'm having is that the client needs to run elevated to administrator privileges to work (which is understandable because it has to open ports in order to communicate with the server)

**Is there any way to configure the client to work without elevation? Or perhaps create a one-time permanent connection so that the client doesn't need to be elevated at all times?**

I'm running out of ideas and google search terms..

**UPDATE**

I've found a solution. Please correct me if there is another best practice I could follow!

I've added an 'Enable' and 'Disable' buttons to the client application that runs netsh to open (or close) and reserve a port.

Enable

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", @"http add urlacl url=http://+:" + PortNumber + @"/ user=DOMAIN\username");
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Disable

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", "http delete urlacl url=http://+:" + PortNumber + "/");
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found a solution. Please correct me if there is another best practice I could follow!

I've added an 'Enable' and 'Disable' buttons to the client application that runs netsh to open (or close) and reserve a port.

Enable

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", @"http add urlacl url=http://+:" + PortNumber + @"/ user=DOMAIN\username");
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Disable

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("netsh", "http delete urlacl url=http://+:" + PortNumber + "/");
process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
process.Start();
process.WaitForExit();
```

Comment: Do you have this working over the internet, if so I would love move information on how to get it working.  What needs to be sets up web and app configs etc...

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can only open a port on Windows when running with administrative privileges.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740548%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

> To use a socket of type SOCK_RAW requires administrative privileges.
>   Users running Winsock applications that use raw sockets must be a
>   member of the Administrators group on the local computer, otherwise
>   raw socket calls will fail with an error code of WSAEACCES. On Windows
>   Vista and later, access for raw sockets is enforced at socket
>   creation. In earlier versions of Windows, access for raw sockets is
>   enforced during other socket operations.
>
> Raw sockets offer the capability to manipulate the underlying
>   transport, so they can be used for malicious purposes that pose a
>   security threat. Therefore, only members of the Administrators group
>   can create sockets of type SOCK_RAW on Windows 2000 and later.

edit:
If you have access to the machine as admin, you can use netsh http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725935(v=ws.10).aspx to permit certain user opening a port.

netsh http add urlacl url=`http://+:80/Uri` user=DOMAIN\User listen=yes

Comment: Is it possible to open a port (as an elevated user) and connect to it again later?

Essentially I just need my ServiceClient to connect, it doesn't necessarily have to recreate the socket each time.

Am I at all on the right track?

Comment: I havent seen your updated question. You should add your update as an answer and, if there is no better solition coming up, acceppt it as the solution. Maybe also add a link to the documentation.